# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i has implemented volley library android. but i have get error `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null`, the URL rquest is `http://23.89.192.247/tanker-dev/index.php/api/masuk`,
this my code:

```
 queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
             Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();    
             jsonParams.put("username",user);
             jsonParams.put("password", password);                
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, 
                    new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Toast.makeText(SplashLoginActivity.this, ""+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(SplashLoginActivity.this, ""+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {     

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
                    headers.put("WWW-Authenticate", "None");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

How to fix it ? sorry for my english...

Comment: whats the error number?

Comment: It's propably error 401 ...